# Check time in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes a lot of time to execute. We want it to execute during the night, but it has to check for the current time every now and then, and at a given time it has to stop executing. How do I do that? Please provide me with the code I can use in my stored procedure. We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current date:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Stop executing:

```
If @date > GETDATE()
    RETURN --Exits procedure
```

Where @date is the date/time when you want to stop executing

Answer (score 0):

Create Maintenance plan and sprecify start time for it. Create "Execute T-SQL statement task" in this plan and specify execution timeout for it (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Why woudl you want to exist a proc that is not finished? Wouldn't you be leaving things in a bad state as far as data integrity or rolling back all the work you just did??

Wouldn't it be a better solution to try to improve the performance of the proc?

Comment: The proc does a certain job like 500 times (for different projects), and it is ok for it to end as long as it ends between one of those jobs.